# How to upload video/audio files from web, to NodeJS, to Google Cloud Storage?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

This is unfamiliar ground for me and I've been poking around with resources trying to find a suitable solution. But essentially, I have a website setup that I want to allow users to upload MP3/FLAC files. Then I want to take those files and send them to a Google Cloud Bucket. The second part seems easy enough, plenty of NodeJS tutorials regarding that.

Since I'm pretty in the dark with how this is done, would I need to "upload" a file on my frontend and then hit my node-express api backend with some sort of `fs.` solution that looks up the file on my machine? If so, how could that be consistent between users, what if their directory structure is different on their machines?

Anyway, kinda shooting in the dark here. Would love to have some advice regarding this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not really feasible for a backend to "reach into" a frontend machine to pull files from it.  The client needs to provide the data directly to the backend.

Mostly commonly, [Firebase client libraries](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage) are used to directly upload contents from a client machine to a storage bucket.  If you don't do that, you'll need to create your own backend API that clients can invoke to send data.